# Is there a way to optimize FLANNBASED matcher in opencv

Tags: android, opencv, feature-detection

I have been comparing different features with different matches to see how accurate and how fast they can be matched. My focus is now in ORB detector ORB extractor BruteforceHamming matcher and SURF detector SURF extractor FLANNBASED matcher. ORB methods seem to be more accurate and faster in small amount of dataset. But SURF and FLANNBASED are better in large dataset.
My question is: Is there a way to optimize FLANNBASED matcher by giving index parameter or search parameter on the basis of opencv lib?